# Use of "für" und "gegen" together with "Barriere"

Tags: synonym

Man findet sowohl den Gebrauch "Barriere für etwas" als auch "Barriere gegen etwas", wird das "für" und "gegen" hier einfach synonym verwendet oder gibt es Unterschiede in der Bedeutung?

One can find both the use of "barrier for something" and "barrier against something", is the "for" and "against" used synonymously or are there differences in meaning?

Comment: Eigentlich ist das keine Frage für GSE: Wie du selber an deiner englischen Übersetzung sehen kannst, gilt deine Beobachtung nicht nur für die deutsche Sprache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im Zusammenhang mit Barrieren wird normalerweise die Präposition *gegen* verwendet, um den *Gegner* anzuzeigen, vor dem die Barriere schützen soll. Die Präposition *für* zeigt normalerweise an, *für* wen die Barriere den Schutz darstellt. Zum Beispiel dient die Haut dem Körper als Barriere; der Gegner sind Keime, also

> Die Haut bildet *für* unseren Körper eine Barriere *gegen* Keime.

aber nicht etwa

> <s>Die Haut bildet *gegen* unseren Körper eine Barriere *für* Keime.</s>

Das heißt, *für* und *gegen* haben unterschiedliche Funktionen und sind nicht synonym.

---

**Zusatz:**

@DavidVogt weist in einem Kommentar darauf hin, dass die Präposition *für* oft denjenigen bezeichnen würde, der durch die Barriere gebremst werde. Das halte ich für standardsprachlich nicht korrekt. Es gibt zwar Konstruktionen wie beispielsweise

> eine Barriere ***für* jemand** darstellen

Allerdings bedeuten das meines Erachtens etwas anderes, was man durch Umstellen des fettgedruckten Teils in der Phrase leichter erkennen kann:

> ***für* jemand** eine Barriere (*gegen* sich selbst) darstellen

Die Ursprüngliche Phrase ist demnach eine Verkürzung, bei der der Gegner nicht explizit genannt wird, weil der, mehr oder weniger zufällig, mit demjenigen übereinstimmt, *für* den sich etwas als eine Barriere darstellt. Kurzum, die Präposition *für* bezieht sich hier auf denjenigen, für den sich irgendetwas darstellt, in diesem Beispiel eben als eine Barriere gegen sich selbst. Aber das könnte auch etwas anderes sein, wie in „***für* jemand** Angst um sich selbst darstellen“ oder „***für* jemand** eine Freude darstellen“ und dergleichen mehr.

Comment: *Für* bezeichnet sehr oft denjenigen oder dasjenige, der durch die Barriere gebremst wird: *Barrieren für Wachstum, Frauen, den Einstieg* etc.

Comment: @DavidVogt, und genau das halte ich für standardsprachlich nicht korrekt. Das ist das Gleiche wie *Antibiotika für/gegen* oder allgemein *ein Medikament für/gegen*, was einige Leute umgangssprachlich auch dort mit der Präposition *für* verwenden, wo *gegen* richtig wäre.

Comment: "Für" kann halt einfach verschiedene Bedeutungen haben, es kann "aus der Sicht von" heißen ("Für Sophie ist das langweilig"), oder "zugunsten von" ("Wir sammeln Geld für das Müttergenesungswerk"). Inkorrekt finde ich da nichts.

Comment: @HalvarF, im Prinzip wollte ich genau das sagen. Es sind verschiedene Bedeutungen und damit keine Synonyme, was der Fragesteller ja wissen wollte. Inkorrekt finde ich nur, wenn *für* eben doch als Synonym von *gegen* verwendet wird, wie etwa bei *eine Barriere für Bakterien* anstelle von *eine Barriere gegen Bakterien*.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: *gegen* ist in solchen Fällen m. E. richtig, das hilft aber nicht gegen die reichlichen anderen Vorkommnisse von *für* siehe z. B. [DWDS-Corpora](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=bz&q=Barriere). Ich erwarte, dass *für* in absehbarer Zeit als ebenfalls als richtig in den Nachschlagewerken erscheint. Das Beispiel *Für kleine Hunde bietet die robuste Umzäunung zudem keine ausreichende Barriere* lässt sich zwar mit *darstellen* sauber umformulieren, das *(gegen sich selbst)* hilft der Erklärung aber nicht: der Satz gibt die Information einfach nicht nicht her.

Comment: @guidot, das Problem in diesem Satz ist aber wiederum die Wahl des Verbs *bieten*, das an sich positiv besetzt ist (jemand etwas bieten, versprechen, in Aussicht stellen, darreichen). Nun wird den Hunden aber nicht eine ganz tolle Barriere geboten, über die sie sich dann freuen können, sondern die robuste Umzäunung stellt sich den Hunden als Barriere dar. Der Satz müsste also eigentlich so oder so ähnlich lauten: *„Für Hunde stellt die robuste Umzäunung zudem keine ausreichende Barriere dar.“* Und das ist, o Wunder, die gleiche Konstruktion wie im Zusatz zu meiner Antwort ...

Comment: ... Das Verb *bieten* würde ich also nicht zur Bezeichnung des Gegners, wohl aber des Nutznießers verwenden, also beispielsweise: *„Für die Schafe bietet die robuste Umzäunung dennoch keine ausreichende Barriere (gegen Wölfe).“*